# why does javascript display <br> astext

Tags: javascript, tags, innerhtml

I have this script:

```html
<input type="number" id="userInput"=></input>
<button onclick="test()">Submit</button>
<p id="cmdpvp"></p>
<p id="cmdsafe"></p>
<p id="cmdscore"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">

function test(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var x = 20;
    var y = parseInt(userInput)
 var z = x + y;
    document.getElementById("cmdpvp").innerHTML = '<p><b>Command for PVPZone:</b></p><br><textarea rows="10" cols="100" id="html" name="html">/summon falling_block ~ ~1 ~ <br> {Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/fill ~-1 ~-3 ~-2 ~3 ~-8 ~1 bedrock 0 hollow"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~0 ~-8 ~-1 minecraft:command_block 0 replace {Command:\"effect @a[r=' + z + ',score_PVPZone=1] minecraft:mining_fatigue 0 0\"}"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~0 ~-8 ~-1 minecraft:command_block 0 replace {Command:\"effect @a[r=' + z + ',score_PVPZone=1] minecraft:regeneration 0 0\"}"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~1 ~-11 ~0 minecraft:command_block 0 replace {Command:\"gamemode 0 @a[r=' + z + ',score_PVPZone=0]\"}"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~1 ~-11 ~0 command_block 0 replace {Command:\"scoreboard players set @a[r=' + z + ',score_PVPZone=0] PVPZone 1\"}"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~1 ~-11 ~0 command_block 0 replace {Command:\"scoreboard players set @a[r=' + z + ',score_SafeZone_min=1] SafeZone 0\"}"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~0 ~-11 ~0 repeating_command_block 0 replace {auto:1b,Command:\"testfor @a[r=' + userInput + ',score_PVPZone=0]\"}"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~1 ~-12 ~0 minecraft:unpowered_comparator 1"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~2 ~-13 ~0 command_block 0 replace {Command:\"fill ~-1 ~-1 ~-1 ~-1 ~-3 ~-1 minecraft:redstone_block\"}"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~2 ~-17 ~-1 command_block 0 replace {Command:\"tellraw @a[r=' + z + ',score_PVPZone=0] [\\\"\\\",{\\\"text\\\":\\\"WARNING!!!!\\\",\\\"color\\\":\\\"red\\\"},{\\\"text\\\":\\\" You are now in the PVPZone!\\\"}]\"}"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~2 ~-17 ~-1 command_block 0 replace {Command:\"fill ~-1 ~-1 ~ ~-1 ~1 ~ minecraft:air\"}"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~2 ~-19 ~0 glowstone"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~0 ~-20 ~0 glowstone"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/fill ~ ~-14 ~-1 ~ ~2 ~ air"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/fill ~ ~-15 ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 redstone_block"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:redstone_block,Time:1<br>}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}</textarea><input type="button" value="Copy PVPZone" onclick="copy_to_clipboard(html);">';
 document.getElementById("cmdsafe").innerHTML = '<br><br><p><b>Command for SafeZone:</b></p><br><textarea rows="10" cols="100" id="test" name="htmltest">/summon falling_block ~ ~1 ~ <br>{Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/fill ~-1 ~-8 ~-2 ~3 ~-3 ~1 bedrock 0 hollow"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~0 ~-8 ~0 command_block 0 replace {Command:\"scoreboard players set @a[r=' + z + ',score_PVPZone_min=1] PVPZone 0\"}"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~0 ~-8 ~0 command_block 0 replace {Command:\"scoreboard players set @a[r=' + z + ',score_SafeZone=0] SafeZone 1\"}"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~0 ~-8 ~0 command_block 0 replace {Command:\"gamemode 2 @a[r=' + z + ',score_SafeZone=1]\"}"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~0 ~-8 ~0 repeating_command_block 0 replace {auto:1b,Command:\"testfor @a[r=' + userInput + ',score_SafeZone=0]\"}"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~1 ~-12 ~0 repeating_command_block 0 replace {auto:1b,Command:\"effect @a[score_SafeZone_min=1] minecraft:weakness 2 255 true\"}"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~1 ~-12 ~0 repeating_command_block 0 replace {auto:1b,Command:\"effect @a[score_SafeZone_min=1] minecraft:regeneration 2 255 true\"}"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~1 ~-12 ~0 stone"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~1 ~-12 ~0 minecraft:unpowered_comparator 1"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~1 ~-16 ~-1 command_block 0 replace {Command:\"tellraw @a[r=' + z + ',score_SafeZone=0] [\\\"\\\",{\\\"text\\\":\\\"RELAX!!!!\\\",\\\"color\\\":\\\"green\\\"},{\\\"text\\\":\\\" You are now in the SafeZone!\\\"}]\"}"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~1 ~-16 ~-1 command_block 0 replace {Command:\"fill ~-1 ~-1 ~ ~-1 ~1 ~ minecraft:air\"}"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~1 ~-16 ~-1 repeating_command_block 0 replace {auto:1b,Command:\"effect @a[score_SafeZone_min=1] minecraft:mining_fatigue 2 255 true\"}"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~2 ~-16 ~0 command_block 0 replace {Command:\"/fill ~-2 ~-1 ~-1 ~-2 ~-3 ~-1 minecraft:redstone_block\"}"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/setblock ~2 ~-19 ~0 glowstone"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/fill ~ ~-14 ~-1 ~ ~2 ~ air"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:<br>{Command:"/fill ~ ~-15 ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 redstone_block"},Passengers:<br>[{id:falling_block,Block:redstone_block,Time:1<br>}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}</textarea><input type="button" value="Copy Safezone" onclick="copy_to_clipboardtest(html);">';
 document.getElementById("cmdscore").innerHTML = '<br><br><p><b>Commands you have to paste in your chat:</b></p><br><textarea rows="1" cols="100" id="test" name="htmltest">/scoreboard objectives add SafeZone dummy</textarea><input type="button" value="Copy Command" onclick="copy_to_clipboardpvpscore(pvp);"><br><textarea rows="1" cols="100" id="test" name="htmltest">/scoreboard objectives add PVPZone dummy</textarea><input type="button" value="Copy Command" onclick="copy_to_clipboardsafescore(safe);">';

}
function copy_to_clipboard(html)
{
    document.getElementById('html').select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
function copy_to_clipboardtest(html)
{
    document.getElementById('test').select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
function copy_to_clipboardpvpscore(pvp)
{
    document.getElementById('test').select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
function copy_to_clipboardsafescore(safe)
{
    document.getElementById('test').select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
</script>
```

The javascript is a html webpage. you enter a number and it generates a script. I know it's probably not made very smart and there's a simpler way. When you click the submit-button and a script appears it displays the <br> as text. Shouldn't it work when it's innerHTML? Can anyone explain?

Comment: How do I break the line in a textarea?

Comment: Because you can't run HTML in a textarea it will be treated as a string not an element... replace `<br>` with `\n`

Comment: `<br>` inside a `<textarea>` is `<br>` ... use `\n` instead for newline inside a `<textarea>`

Comment: Do you intend for people to be able to edit the `text` in the `textarea`s? You may want to consider using `div` elements with `contenteditable` instead.

Answer (score 0):

One way out is to use a regular expression to find and replace all the br

Here is one that replaces it with a new line:

```
.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/g, '\n')
```

If you want to create your own regular expression and use it with ".replace", [Rubular](http://rubular.com) is a good ressource!

Comment: The strings are coded in the javascript so the OP should have full control over it... why the need to use `.replace()` when the OP can simple replace them with `\n`. This solution would make sense if the string were return from an outside source but you can clearly see that isn't the case..

Comment: That's true. Even better.